# ERROR: "Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Iam pretty new at developing websites in ASP.NET, or just websites in general.

I have programmed a website, which on Localhost works perfectly fine, but when I put it online I get this error when i try to upload a file.

Code:

```
FileUpload_Billede.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/upload/") + FileUpload_Billede.FileName);
MakeThumb(FileUpload_Billede.FileName, "img/upload/", 295, "/img/sponsor/");
```

I have put another site up on the same webhotel where I also used FileUpload, yet no error appeared.

I have read a lot on the internet saying it is IIS that causes the problem. I have never touched IIS before which is why I don't understand why there will be a problem with it now? In which case I have no idea what to do in the IIS Manager program. I hope someone can help me with this is as I am totally lost.

Let me know if you need more any information.

EDIT: I've been asked to write the definition of the MakeThumb method. Here it is:

```
private void MakeThumb(string Filename, string UploadFolder, int bredde, string thumbuploadfolder)
{
    // Kompliceret Kode fundet fra nettet om upload og skalering af billede.

    // find det uploadede image
    System.Drawing.Image OriginalImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/") + UploadFolder + Filename);

    // find højde og bredde på image
    int originalWidth = OriginalImg.Width;
    int originalHeight = OriginalImg.Height;

    // bestem den nye bredde på det thumbnail som skal laves
    int newWidth = bredde;

    // beregn den nye højde på thumbnailbilledet
    double ratio = newWidth / (double)originalWidth;
    int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(ratio * originalHeight);


    Bitmap Thumb = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Thumb.SetResolution(OriginalImg.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImg.VerticalResolution);

    // Hvis billedet indeholder nogen form for transperans 
    //(mere eller mindre gennemsigtig, eller en gennemsigtig baggrund) bliver det gjort her
    Thumb.MakeTransparent();


    // opret det nye billede
    Graphics ThumbMaker = Graphics.FromImage(Thumb);
    ThumbMaker.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    ThumbMaker.DrawImage(OriginalImg,
        new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight),
        new Rectangle(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // encoding
    ImageCodecInfo encoder;
    string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Filename);
    switch (fileExt)
    {
        case ".png":
            encoder = GetEncoderInfo("image/png");
            break;

        case ".gif":
            encoder = GetEncoderInfo("image/gif");
            break;

        default:
            // default til JPG 
            encoder = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
            break;
    }

    EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);

    // gem thumbnail i mappen /Images/Uploads/Thumbs/
    Thumb.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + thumbuploadfolder + Filename, encoder, encoderParameters);

    // Fjern originalbilledet, thumbnail mm, fra computerhukommelsen
    OriginalImg.Dispose();
    ThumbMaker.Dispose();
    Thumb.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: Please post SaveAs and MakeThumb function definition.

Comment: SaveAs is defined by default, not by me. I posted the definition of MakeThumb.

Comment: Place a breakpoint at `FileUpload_Billede.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/upload/") + FileUpload_Billede.FileName);` and see what the path is

Answer (score 0):

try to add DMS folder at your main website folder ,then from properties change the permissions to make everyone can read/write on this folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that img/upload folder exist on your server and it should be accessible.

Comment: The folder exist already. As i said, when i run the website on Localhost i can uploade fine without problems. The problem occurs when I try to upload a file from the online website. But the folders is there aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Check exactly where the error is and narrow down to that - we don't need full implementation of the MakeThumb, just the bit where the error is.

The folders might exist, but your application's app pool's identity might not have access.

Check both folders (some of the comments mention "the folder" yet the thumbs are saved to a different folder.

If possible, deploy with Debug (rather than Release) to get line numbers, if not, adding some logging (eg log4net) or tracing and add details of the paths.

Use `System.IO.Directory.Exists()` before attempting to save

It's likely one of `.SaveAs`, `FromFile`, `Thumb.Save` - also you use different implementations for each of these.

As an extra: always use `Path.System.IO.Path.Combine()` so there's no possibility of extra `//` which can caused problems